# CFGRID with CF 9.0.1

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a CFgrid that was working fine in CF 9.0, but now we have upgraded to 9.0.1, nothing comes up form (form.#GridName#.#Column1Name#) after the form is submitted. I made up some test code (below) which i have tried on a 9.0.1 server, which comes up with empty string in the form, were as on a 9.0 it somes up with all the info for the selected row. Any ideas on what the problem is and any fixes for it?

Cheers in advance

```
    DUMP form: <cfdump var="#form#"><br>

<cfform action="#CGI.script_name#" method="post">

<cfset args = structNew()>
<cfset args.name   = "requestGrid">
<cfset args.format   = "html">
<cfset args.stripeRows  = true>
<cfset args.selectmode  = "row">
<cfset args.height   = "150">
<cfset arg.width   = "320">
<cfset args.autowidth  = "yes">
<cfset args.gridLines  = "yes">
<cfgrid attributeCollection="#args#">
 <cfgridcolumn name="iRequestProductID"  display="false">
 <cfgridcolumn name="iItemID"    display="false">
 <cfgridcolumn name="iProductID"   display="false">
 <cfgridcolumn name="productName"   header="Requested Product"  width="150" > 
 <cfgridcolumn name="ItemName"    header="Allocated Item"  width="100" dataAlign="center"> 
 <cfgridcolumn name="sSerialNo"    header="Serial no"    width="100" dataAlign="center"> 

 <cfgridrow data = "1,1,2,test1,aaa,123">
 <cfgridrow data = "1,2,2,test2,bbb,234">
 <cfgridrow data = "1,3,2,test3,ccc,345">
 <cfgridrow data = "1,4,2,test4,ddd,456">
 <cfgridrow data = "1,5,2,test5,eee,567">

</cfgrid>

<input type="Submit" name="allocate"  value="Allocate Item" style="color:ff0000" />

</cfform>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the enhancements in ColdFusion 9.0.1:

- In ColdFusion 9, data for the first row is available on form submission in a form with dynamic grid. In ColdFusion 9.0.1, the data is not available.

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7baf.html

Comment: I did see that, but does that mean that the whole "Returning cfgrid data to the action page" and "Simple selection data" section sdoes now not work? And on a side note, how can they possibly call this an enhancement???

Comment: Simon I havent tried it but from the sounds of it Adobe has changed the behavior a bit